# Passing Arguments to Inner Function

Tags: python, function, datetime, flask-sqlalchemy

I wrote a little helper function to check how many movies I've added to my Flask-SQLAlchemy table in the last `x` hours/minutes/days:

```
#### Check how many movies were added in the last X (hours, minutes) Y (int)
def movies_added_last(x,y):
    current_time = dateconvert.arrow.utcnow().naive
    tf_hours_ago = current_time - timedelta(x = y)
    movies_within_the_last_tf = models.Movie.query.filter(models.Movie.timeadded > tf_hours_ago).count()
    print movies_within_the_last_tf
```

The goal is to be able to call it like so: (hours,24) or (minutes,10).

First of all, `x` is being recognized by [`timedelta()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects) as an invalid attribute, as it only accepts arguments like `hours`, `minutes`, and `weeks`. `timedelta()` isn't treating `x` as a variable.

How can I make this function work?

**EDIT**

I should explain myself a bit better:

`x` is supposed to be the format argument that is passed to timedelta, and `y` is supposed to be the integer argument, so when I call `movies_added_last(seconds, 60)` I want movies added in the last 60 seconds, another way to say it is that I want the inner timedelta to evaluate as `timedelta(seconds = 60)`.

Comment: sorry, what is `timedelta(x=y)` supposed to do?  do you want `timedelta(**{x:y})`?

Comment: these are supposed to be the variables I passed. `tf_hours_ago = current_time - timedelta(hours=24)` will yield me (in this function) all movies added within the last 24 hours. but timedelta isn't treating x as a variable it should check the value of first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to me like you want to use:   `timedelta(**{x:y})` rather than `timedelta(x=y)`.

With the latter, you're passing a default argument named `x` (with value `y`) to `timedelta`.  With the former, you're passing a default argument whose name is the *value* of `x` (still with a value of `y`) to `timedelta`.  e.g.

```
>>> from datetime import timedelta
>>> x = 'hours'
>>> timedelta(x=3)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'x' is an invalid keyword argument for this function
>>> timedelta(**{x:3})
datetime.timedelta(0, 10800)
```

If you do this, then you'll call your function like so:

```
 movies_added_last('seconds', 60)
 movies_added_last('minutes', 20)
 # etc.
```

---

Other alternatives (which might be cleaner) are to unpack keyword arguments to your function:

```
def movies_added_last(**kwargs):
    current_time = dateconvert.arrow.utcnow().naive
    tf_hours_ago = current_time - timedelta(**kwargs)
    movies_within_the_last_tf = models.Movie.query.filter(models.Movie.timeadded > tf_hours_ago).count()
    print movies_within_the_last_tf
```

Now you can call this with any keyword arguments that you can use to call `timedelta`:

```
movies_added_last(seconds=60)
movies_added_last(minutes=20)
# etc.
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I want to explain better: x is supposed to be the format argument that is passed to timedelta, and y is supposed to be the integer, so when I call movies_added_last(seconds, 60) I want movies added in the last 60 seconds. I want the inner timedelta to evaluate as timedelta(seconds = 60)

Comment: @zerohedge -- Maybe I'm dense, but I'm still not getting it.  do you mean you want to call `movies_added_last('seconds', 60)`?  Because I think that my solution here will work.  Other alternatives are `movies_added_last(seconds=60)` which is workable as well (and I've added an example for that solution as well)...

Comment: Thank you, this worked! Now I just need to understand the logic behind it! (I wonder what "still with the value of y" means)

Comment: @zerohedge -- Sorry, terminology gets muddy at this point.  When you say `y = 50`, you have a variable named "y" with a value of `50`.  So when I say "still with the value of y", I just mean that the dictionary passed will look like `{'seconds': 60}`.  All of that blabbering is probably just distracting from what you already intuitively know.  :-/